# DjangoAppEngine TestApp

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel

Need some help starting up the djangoappengine testapp.I followed the instructions at http://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine, but when I run ./manage.py runserver  .  while in the project directory I get the following error:

```
WARNING  2011-03-24 12:23:21,994 datastore_file_stub.py:657] Could not read datastore
data from /media/disk/Projex/AppEngineApp/app/.gaedata/datastore  
Error: option --rdbms_sqlite_path not recognized
Runs a development application server for an application.
manage.py [options] <application root>__
```

When I try and comment  the '    'rdbms_sqlite_path': os.path.join(DATA_ROOT, 'rdbms'),' line in app/djangoappengine/db/base.py I get the following error:

```
WARNING  2011-03-24 12:26:07,239 datastore_file_stub.py:657] Could not read datastore  
data from /media/disk/Projex/AppEngineApp/app/.gaedata/datastore
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 11, in <module>
execute_manager(settings)
File "/media/disk/Projex/AppEngineApp/app/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 438,   
in execute_manager
utility.execute()
File "/media/disk/Projex/AppEngineApp/app/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 379,  
in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File   
"/media/disk/Projex/AppEngineApp/app/djangoappengine/management/commands/runserver.py",  
line 94, in run_from_argv
start_dev_appserver(argv)
File 
"/media/disk/Projex/AppEngineApp/app/djangoappengine/management/commands/runserver.py",   
line 81, in start_dev_appserver
dev_appserver_main.main([progname] + args + [PROJECT_DIR])
File "/usr/local/gaepy/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver_main.py", line 426, in main
static_caching=static_caching)
File "/usr/local/gaepy/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3820, in   
CreateServer
server = HTTPServerWithScheduler((serve_address, port), handler_class)
File "/usr/local/gaepy/google/appengine/tools/dev_appserver.py", line 3840, in __init__
request_handler_class)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 400, in __init__
self.server_bind()
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 108, in server_bind
SocketServer.TCPServer.server_bind(self)
File "/usr/lib/python2.6/SocketServer.py", line 411, in server_bind
self.socket.bind(self.server_address)
File "<string>", line 1, in bind
socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

Anyone experienced this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably already solved this, but for future users:

The warning can have multiple causes:

- data store is empty, [in that case ignore](http://code.google.com/p/app-engine-patch/issues/detail?id=155)
- wrong permissions on the datastore files
- data corruption issue

The error can be solved [by updating djangoappengine](https://bitbucket.org/wkornewald/djangoappengine/issue/34/error-option-rdbms_sqlite_path-not)

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest version of google app engine.